# Using UI Automator as the locator when using Appium and RobotFramework

Tags: android, appium, robotframework

I am trying to use `UI Automator` as the locator for clicking some elements.  For reference I'm using `RobotFramework` and the `robotframework-appiumlibrary`.

The snippet I'm trying to use is:

```java
Click Element  android=new UiSelector().description('arbitraryDescription')
```

From [the documentation](http://jollychang.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/doc/AppiumLibrary.html) that looks like it should work.

However this fails every time with the following output:

> WebDriverException: Message: The requested resource could not be
>   found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not
>   supported by the mapped resource.

I'm largely confused because I'm distinctly not trying to call the WebDriver and I don't know why I'm getting that instead of the UI Automator.

Comment: Just to clarify, as soon as you call "Click Element" you are calling WebDriver. Robot framework itself has no way of interacting with webpages, it needs a library for that such as Selenium or Appium. What these Selenium and Appium libraries do is mostly abstracting the calls that you would need to make to WebDriver in order to get the intended result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out the documentation was wrong as is described here: https://github.com/jollychang/robotframework-appiumlibrary/issues/96

The following is what the documentation says should work:

```
Click Element android=new UiSelector().description('arbitraryDescription')
```

And this is what actually works:

```
Click Element android=UiSelector().description('arbitraryDescription')
```

I made the relevant edits and created a pull request hopefully nobody else gets stuck in the trap I did.